# Typescript LanguageService does not provide autocomplete information for array types

Tags: typescript

I've implemented a java-bridge to the Typescript LanguageService (https://github.com/BestSolution-at/java2typescript) who works quite smooth but I've got the following problem.

Let's assume I have the following Typescript-File (sample.ts)

```
class Person {
    firstname : string;
    lastname : string;
    friendList : Person[];

    constructor(firstname : string, lastname : string) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public getName() {
        return this.lastname + ", " + this.firstname;
    }

    public getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
}

var p : Person = new Person("Tom","Schindl");
p.
```

Executing the following Java-Code (API is the same as LanguageService API):

```
CompletionInfo info = service.getCompletionsAtPosition(fileId, 424);
info.entries().stream().forEach( i -> {
  service.getCompletionEntryDetails(fileId, 424, i.name());
});
```

Provides me the following information (encoded as JSON):

```
{
  "requestIdRef": 4,
  "result": {
    "name": "firstname",
    "kindModifiers": "",
    "kind": "property",
    "displayParts": [
      {
        "text": "(",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": "property",
        "kind": "text"
      },
      {
        "text": ")",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": " ",
        "kind": "space"
      },
      {
        "text": "Person",
        "kind": "className"
      },
      {
        "text": ".",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": "firstname",
        "kind": "propertyName"
      },
      {
        "text": ":",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": " ",
        "kind": "space"
      },
      {
        "text": "string",
        "kind": "keyword"
      }
    ],
    "documentation": [

    ]
  }
}
```

...

```
{
  "requestIdRef": 6,
  "result": {
    "name": "friendList",
    "kindModifiers": "",
    "kind": "property",
    "displayParts": [
      {
        "text": "(",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": "property",
        "kind": "text"
      },
      {
        "text": ")",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": " ",
        "kind": "space"
      },
      {
        "text": "Person",
        "kind": "className"
      },
      {
        "text": ".",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": "friendList",
        "kind": "propertyName"
      },
      {
        "text": ":",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": " ",
        "kind": "space"
      },
      {
        "text": "{",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      },
      {
        "text": "}",
        "kind": "punctuation"
      }
    ],
    "documentation": [

    ]
  }
}
```

As you notice the completion details for a property with a builtin type is working (last segment in displayParts) whereas for custom types I get no information.

As VS-Code is displaying the information it must be available, the strange thing is that looking at their code they issue the same LanguageService calls than I do (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/languages/typescript/common/features/suggestions.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I forgot to load lib.d.ts upfront. Loading lib.d.ts fixes the problem!

Comment: ...and how to load `lib.d.ts`?

Comment: Ship it with and when configuring the project just load it from the filesystem